# Import CSV alternative method using PHP and MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the code below to import a CSV textfile into my table, but my new host not allowing `LOAD DATA` commands and forces me to find alternative ways of importing the file. Naturally, they are useless in giving me a clear answer.

What other ways except `LOAD DATA LOCAL` and `LOAD DATA` do I have to import a CSV file into my MySQL table via PHP/MySQLi?

```
  // Query - import CSV file into DB, ignore top 3 lines
    $sql= "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$import_file."' INTO TABLE `$dbtable`
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY '".$fieldseparator."'
       LINES TERMINATED BY '".$lineseparator."'
       IGNORE 3 LINES
       SET TIMESTAMP = '".$local_time."'";
```

Thanks

EDIT:

After looking into the suggested `fgetcsv` function, I came up with the below code. Theoretically, it should work, but the code seems to load until it finally times out without showing an error. The database is populated with a single row entry only.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
                if ($import_file) {
                  // set row counter to 0
                  $line = 0;

                  while ( ($row = fgetcsv($import_file)) !== false ) {

                    // ignore the first 3 rows of the file based on iteration of the counter
                    if ($line <= 3) {
                      $line++;
                      continue;
                    } else {

                        // if row count is higher than 3, insert into database
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO `$dbtable`
                          (`OPERA_CONF`, `CRS`, `HOLIDEX`, `ARRIVAL`)
                          VALUES (
                            '" . $row[0] . "',
                            '" . $row[1] . "',
                            '" . $row[2] . "',
                            '" . $row[3] . "'
                          )";

                        // execute query
                        $mysqli->query($sql);
                        $line++;

                    }

                  }

                } else {
                    echo "\n CSV file could not be found.";
                }
```

Comment: You got no access to phpmyadmin ?

Comment: @Ashish I do, but the script running this query is bound to a cronjob and supposed to run every 15min. Without the `LOAD DATA` command I cannot do anything (or at least I dont know how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to use PHP to read the contents of the CSV file line by line and insert them into the table.

Have a look at http://www.readmyviews.com/import-csv-data-mysql-using-php/

Code pasted here for easy of use:

```
$filepath = "C:\wamp\www\importdata\sample.csv"; 

if (($getdata = fopen($filepath, "r")) !== FALSE) {
               fgetcsv($getdata);   
               while (($data = fgetcsv($getdata)) !== FALSE) {
                    $fieldCount = count($data);
                    for ($c=0; $c < $fieldCount; $c++) {
                      $columnData[$c] = $data[$c];
                    }
             $option_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect ,$columnData[0]);
             $option_value = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect ,$columnData[1]);
             $import_data[]="('".$option_name."','".$option_value."')";
            // SQL Query to insert data into DataBase

             }
             $import_data = implode(",", $import_data);
             $query = "INSERT INTO option_data_master(option_name,option_value) VALUES  $import_data ;";
             $result = mysqli_query($connect ,$query);
```

Comment: Thanks for that Nick, just not sure what the purpose of `option_data_master(option_name,option_value)` is? Are those column names? Can you have a look at my posted code perhaps? Thanks

Comment: No problem :) Your code looks good. How big is the CSV file you are trying to import?

Comment: Tiny, max 500 rows with 25 columns each row. The whole thing just loads and then stops without any error message.

Comment: Try changing `$mysqli->query($sql);` to  `if (!mysqli->query($sql))
  {
  printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
  }`

Comment: Thanks, managed to figure it out. The problem was that the missing `fopen()` which caused the file location to be read as a string instead of an  object. Works well now, thanks a lot!